Push notifications endpoint HTTP v1
I don't understand a bit about the termination of support for the firebase API. Will this affect the usual sites that work through the endpoint?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/endpoint
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?
Can you help me please?
Also started getting errors when sending push notifications.

Hello, what HTTP errors are you getting? That migration should only affect the proprietary FCM API and not the Web Push standard. If you are getting a high number of 404 starting form yesterday, this may be related: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/349646659

@collimarco The error began to be received on June 24 at 17:20 UTC.
We go to the push service, which gives the api(subscription.endpoint), it returns an url of the form https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
and firebase says that it will be abandoned.
I will also clarify that we use our vapid keys, and not through firebase
Help please if you can

When you try to send a push notification to that endpoint, what HTTP response you receive? Please share here the HTTP status code and response body

@collimarco
We send it to the url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/f6XGebrPvNs:APA91bF43rzzq52MYLhxZK2gA9Rm2W7Eb7pkZ4[...]pOlrn2IkapH9bOwNpgWqIJbo6-gfoqNLazGVfgya-RC_Jr9AlW9dSY6BDDL
We get the status code: 404.
Response body:
A valid push subscription endpoint should be specified in the URAL as such: https://fcm.googleapis.com/wp/dHIoDxE7Hdg:APA91bH1Zj0kNa...

It's normal. FCM started removing some inactive subscriptions: related discussions with response from Google are available here and here.
